# How to prove that eigenvalues of a rotation matrix in $\text{SO}(3)$ are $e^{(i\theta)}$ , $e^{(−i\theta)}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

> How to prove that eigenvalues of a rotation matrix in $\text{SO}(3)$ are $e^{(i\theta)}$ , $e^{(−i\theta)}$?

Here, $\theta$ is the angle of rotation and $i$ is $\sqrt{-1}$ .

Edit 1:

I have been able to prove that there is one eigenvalue of 1, and other two are complex conjugates of each other. This comes from the fact that the rotation matrix can be written as an exponential $R = e^\omega $ where R is the rotation matrix and $\omega$ is a skew symmetric matrix. I also was able to determine that the axis of rotation is the eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue 1. What I'm not being able to prove is that how are the other eigenvalues related to the angle of rotation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include the work you have done and where you are stuck in the problem so that we can push you in the correct direction.

Comment: You should watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wIn_dlmD8sk  all your doubts will be cleared @anant joshi

Answer (score 2):

From $U U^T=U^T U=1$ you deduce that any eigenvalue  has modulus 1. If $Ux=\lambda x$ then also $U\bar{x}=\bar{\lambda} \bar{x}$ so they come in complex pairs. In dimension 3, at least one eval has to be real and equal to +1 when looking at $SO$.

Suppose $U (x+ iy) = e^{i\theta}(x+ iy) = (\cos \theta +i \sin \theta) (x +iy) \ $ (with $\theta \neq 0$ mod $\pi$). Separating into real and imaginary parts we may write this as:
 $$ U [x \ \ y] = [x \ \ y] 
  \left(\begin{matrix}
        \cos \theta & - \sin \theta\\
        \sin \theta  & \cos \theta 
   \end{matrix} \right)
$$

We claim that $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal and have the same length.

First notice that  $U^T=U^{-1}$ so we also have $U^T (x+iy) = e^{-i\theta} (x+iy)$. From this we see that
 $$  Ux= x \cos \theta - y \sin \theta \ \ \mbox{ and } \ \
  U^T x = x \cos \theta + y \sin \theta.$$
Take e.g. the scalar product with $x$ to obtain:
  $$ x^T U^Tx = (Ux)^T x = x^T U x  \ \ \Rightarrow x^T y \sin \theta =0.$$ 
The assumption $\theta\neq 0$ mod $\pi$ implies that $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal. Calculating $|Ux|^2=|x|^2$ you deduce similarly that $|x|=|y|$.

This gives a very explicit geometric picture of rotation associated with the complex eigenvalues: The vectors $x$ and $y$ form an orthonormal base for a plane which is $U$ invariant and  $U$ performs a rotation by angle $\theta$ in this plane.

Finally, you may notice that the discussion of complex eigenvalues applies in any dimension $\geq 2$.

Comment: But how do we relate the angle of rotation to the other eigenvalues?

Comment: What does the action of U on (x,y) mean?

Comment: That you expand $Ux$ and $Uy$ in terms of $x$ and $y$. You may write this in the matrix form $U [x \  y] = [x \ y] R$  where $R$ is a 2 by 2 matrix of cos and sin. Note that $U$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix, whereas $[x \ y]$ is a $3\times 2$ matrix.

Answer (score 0):

A matrix $U$ in $SO(3)$ has a real eigenvalue since the characteristic polynomial has degree 3. Write $U(x)=cx, c\in R$, $\langle U(x),U(x)\rangle=\langle x,x\rangle$ this implies that $c^2=1$, $c=1$ or $-1$.

Take the plan $P$ orthorgonal to $Vect(x)$, it is stable by $U$ and the restriction of $U$ to $P$ is an orthogonal matrix which has eigenvalue $e^{i\theta}, e^{-i\theta}$.